# Android Monkeyrunner plugin for Wifi state

Tags: java, android, python, jython, monkeyrunner

I am trying to write a java plugin for the Android Monkeyrunner to check the WiFi state.
I would like to use the **Android API WiFiManager** to get the current WiFi state and return it back.

The error message in Eclipse is:
*The method getWifiState() is undefined for the type MonkeyWifi*

How can I change the code to be able to get the current WiFi status?

This is the code I have so far:

```
package com.my.android.wifi;

import org.python.core.PyInteger;
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

import com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

public class MonkeyWifi implements Predicate<PythonInterpreter> {

public class NewActivity extends Activity {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
}

public int WifiStatus(){
    int state;
    state = wifiManager.getWifiState();
    return state;
}


@Override
public boolean apply(PythonInterpreter arg0)    {
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) instead (version **8.26.0** or higher), then you would be able to access basic wifi information.

A basic script to check wifi state would be along these lines

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import WIFI_SERVICE, WifiManager


device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
wifiManager = device.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE)
print "wifi state:", wifiManager.getWifiState()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create an instance of `WifiManager`. According to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm) page, you can do it by calling:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

And then you can get the state by:

```
state = wifiManager.getWifiState();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am new to Java and trying to figure it out. I have changed it according to your input.
I get the following message:
The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type MonkeyWifi

Comment: The method `getSystemService(String)` is part of the `Activity` class, so an easy solution would be creating the `wifiManager` instance inside a class that extends `Activity`.

Comment: You should have a class that `extends Activity`. If the `MonkeyWifi` is created from there, you can create a constructor for it `public MonkeyWifi(WifiManager wifiManager)` and then save the wifiManager as an instance `this.wifiManager = wifiManager;` to be able to use it. Then in the `Activity` class, create the `MonkeyWifi` instance using `new MonkeyWifi((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))`. Other way is making a public instance `public static WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);` in your `Activity` class.

Comment: I tried few thing but couldnt get to a solution. I appreaciate all your help.
Do you mind looking at the code above in the questions?
**wifiManager** in:
**state = wifiManager.getWifiState();**
is not being recognized.